# (homeworkish) unit test a class with random behavior without being able to mock the RNG

Tags: unit-testing, junit, junit4

I'm working through Coursera's Algorithms, Part I course. I have to create a RandomizedQueue with the following API:

```
public class RandomizedQueue<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {
   public RandomizedQueue()                 // construct an empty randomized queue
   public boolean isEmpty()                 // is the queue empty?
   public int size()                        // return the number of items on the queue
   public void enqueue(Item item)           // add the item
   public Item dequeue()                    // delete and return a random item
   public Item sample()                     // return (but do not delete) a random item
   public Iterator<Item> iterator()         // return an independent iterator over items in random order
   public static void main(String[] args)   // unit testing
}
```

**Question**: if I can't create a mock RNG to pass into the structure (because I'm not allowed to alter the API) and I don't want to test private methods, how do I test the random behavior of this structure?

**What I've tried**

I've tried thinking about the results I'd expect as a probabilistic problem. So, for example, I'll run the following pseudocode test 10,000 times:

```
create new RandomizedQueue
enqueue 100 items (e.g. integers 0 - 99)
deque 1 item
```

Then I can test that the frequency with which each of the 100 items is dequed is within a certain confidence interval (based on the binomial distribution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some might call this cheating, but I would [beg to differ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kobayashi_Maru).

---

The point of unit testing is to verify the behavior of a system. As such, if a test is going to be useful at all, it *must* be deterministic. Otherwise you'll occasionally get false negatives, deteriorating the integrity of the test. ("Oh, it's ok if that test fails. It happens sometimes...")

With that in mind, **what if you didn't have the restriction that you couldn't modify the API?** If you had your druthers, how would you implement and test your class? Create *that* implementation first. You can design this class to be fully deterministic.

After you have a working and *tested* class, simply implement `RandomizedQueue<Item>` [as an adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) to your class.

---

#### Example

Consider the following setup:

```
public interface RandomNumberGenerator {
    int GetRandomInt();
}

// Identical to RandomizedQueue<T>, except takes a RandomNumberGenerator as a dependency
public class MyRandomizedQueue<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {

    public MyRandomizedQueue(RandomNumberGenerator generator) {
    ...
}
```

Your tests could provide the SUT with a fake `RandomNumberGenerator` and have complete control over what the expected outcome of any method would be.

In the actual `RandomizedQueue<T>` implementation, you would instantiate your tested class with a *real* `RandomNumberGenerator` implementation (e.g., one that uses `java.util.Random`), store it as a member variable, and forward method calls along to it. Like:

```
public Item dequeue() {
    return innerQueue.dequeue();
}
```

Comment: I assume the next step would be to profile the performance to determine if refactoring to remove the indirection is necessary, correct?

Comment: That wouldn't be a bad idea. But I'd be surprised if an application's performance bottleneck was traced to the overhead of an extra method call. (The Tree of Optimizations usually has much lower-hanging fruit.) :-)